# Which is faster C++ std::string::length or std::string::size?

Tags: c++, string, size, time-complexity, string-length

`length()` returns the number of characters in the string and `size()` returns a `size_t` which is also the same but used to make it consistent with other STL containers.

For computing `length()`, the string iterates through all the characters and counts the length. So, `O(n)` time.

Is `size()` also the same ?

Or can size of a variable be computed directly in `O(1)` time ?

So, my question is, are they the same in terms of speed (as in how they are calculated) or is size computed in `O(1)` time ?

Comment: Try running a loop over a set of datas(And calculate the time) you will know which one is fast.

Comment: What makes you think `length()` is O(n)?

Comment: O(n) in size of input ? because it will have to iterate over all the characters of the string ?

Comment: It doesn't have to iterate.

Comment: So, it just uses the number of bytes required to count the length ?

Comment: "For computing length(), the string iterates through all the characters and counts the length" - where did you get that idea??? `std::string` is designed as a string with *stored* length. It does not have to iterate.

Comment: I thought that might be because in other STL containers like vector etc. that is what has to be done....

Comment: `vector` doesn't need to iterate either (nor do most (all?) of the standard containers...)

Comment: His idea is not so weird. Properly support of `UTF-8` in `std::string` which - oh, my! - does not exist (while `char*` on *nix platforms is by default `utf8`-encoded), would indeed require iterating. @ronilp You can think of `std::string` simply as of `std::vector<char>`. `length()` has `O(1)` and simply returns `m_Length` or something like that.

Comment: @Oliver: since C++11, `size()` is guaranteed to be `O(1)`, so yes all containers. This required a change to the glibc implementation of `std::list`.

Comment: It is faster to type 'size' than 'length' since it has 2 less characters.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Both have the same complexity: Constant.

From the N4431 working draft, §21.4.4

> `size_type size() const noexcept;`
>
> Returns: A count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string. Complexity: Constant time.

And

> `size_type length() const noexcept;`
>
> Returns: size().

---

> [...] iterates through all the characters and counts the length [...]

That's C strings you're thinking of.

Answer (score 18):

If you take a look at documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) it says that `length` and `size` are the same.

> Both string::size and string::length are synonyms and return the same value.

Also if you take a look at the code, length is cached, so the complexity is `O(1)`. (Code from MS implementation but I'm sure other libraries are done the same way.)

```
size_type length() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mysize);
    }

size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mysize);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the functions for a string in C++ are exactly the same and Returns the number of characters in the string, not including any null-termination.

[image: source]

Source: [basic_string.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/150a829accd76ddd73c20628774cb0781f6e8bfe/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L907)

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent. Also, strings don't count characters when returning size, that's char arrays, if strings always counted characters then they would be too slow.